# kohana: Remove need for default controller route

Tags: php, routes, kohana

I have a route as:

`((?<directory>\w+)/?)?((?<controller>\w+)/?)?((?<action>\w+)/?)?((?<id>\d+))?`

It works fine but it causes my system to have to include the default controller (index) for all routes to the sub routes. For example, if my page URI is `/blog/post` (where blog is the directory and post would be the action), my actual URI would have to be `blog/index/post` - I'd like to be able to fall back to just using `blog/post` instead.

So, I would like it to be routed to:

```
directory = blog
controller = index
action = post
```

Obviously this causes issues when the second parameter is actually a controller. For example `directory/controller/action` would be routed incorrectly.

Is there a routing method to detect that there are three word parameters, possibly followed by a numeric parameter, which can do what I need?

For claification:

- `param/param/param(?/id)` would be: `directory/controller/action(/id)`
- `param/param(?/id)` would be: `directory/default_controller/action(/id)`

Answer (score 3):

i'd actually think that you want to alias `blog/index/post` with `blog/post`; insert it as a route before the "catch-all" route that you have; the "one big shoe fits all" approach is not always the best. Especially, *if* you only have 1 such particular use case.

**edit:**

"kohana's routing system" is daunting; can't make sense of the elephant they're trying to give birth to there... here are some other suggestions:

1. Take this issue to the manufacturer; this is definetely an FAQ question
2. Mess around with the regex patterns. Here's a snippet that might be useful (i put it inside a PHP test case, but you could easily decouple it)

   ```
   public function testRoutePatterns(){
       $data = array(
       array(
           //most specific: word/word/word/id
           '~^(?P<directory>\w+)/(?P<controller>\w+)/(?P<action>\w+)/(?P<id>.*)$~i', 
           'myModule/blog/post/some-id',
           array('directory'=>'myModule', 'controller'=>'blog', 'action'=>'post', 'id'=>'some-id'), 
           true
       ),
       array(
           //less specific: word/word/id
           '~^(?P<directory>\w+)/(?P<action>\w+)/(?P<id>.*)$~i', 
           'blog/post/some-id',
           array('directory'=>'blog', 'action'=>'post'), //need to inject "index" controller via "defaults()" here i guess
           true
       ),
       );
   foreach ($data as $d) {
       $matches = array();
       list($pattern, $subject, $expected, $bool) = $d;
       $actual = (bool) preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
       $this->assertEquals($bool, $actual); //assert matching
       $this->assertEquals(array(), array_diff($expected, $matches)); //$expected contained in $matches
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: It would be good if it was for one case but I'd like a universal solution

Comment: I think you're going against Kohana's advice if you create just one route to handle everything.  You really need to use multiple routes and organize them to fit your requirements best.  There are some [devtools](https://github.com/bluehawk/devtools) that help you identify which route you're hitting based on your url.  I think Grigorash Vasilij has the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884255/kohana-3-routing-with-subdirectories-error-controller-does-not-exist), if you have some route like this:

```
Route::set('route_name', 'directory/controller/action')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'biz',
        'controller' => 'foo',
        'action'     => 'bar',
    ));
```

You should have the directory structure like this:

```
/application/classes/controller/biz/foo.php
```